# Is my postorder traversal of this graph correct?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, traversal, postorder

I am trying to implement an algorithm that requires a post-order traversal. Here is my graph (taken from [here](https://www.cs.rice.edu/%7Ekeith/EMBED/dom.pdf), pg. 8):

[image]

When I try to do a postorder traversal of this, the order I get is:

```
[3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6]
```

The problem with this order is that the algorithm won't work in this order. This is the code I am using to get it (pseudocode):

```
function PostOrder(root, out_list) {
    root.visited = true
    for child in root.Children {
        if not child.visited {
            PostOrder(child, out_list)
        }
    }
    out_list.append(root)
}
```

Is the postorder correct?

Comment: Your algorithm will produce the list as you provided it. It is also the correct output. What is your question? You write *"the algorithm won't work in this order"*: well, it does give that order as output... Or are you referring to another algorithm?

Comment: What's your root?

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire -- 6

Comment: @trincot -- the algorithm I am implementing won't work with that order...

Comment: Which algorithm are you talking about?

Comment: @Xilpex, multiple paths are possible

Comment: @Xilpex, Trincot's solution is one of the possible answers. Checkout if your answer is one of the 4 lists mentioned at the end of my answer

Comment: Which algorithm are you talking about, and what do you mean with "won't work"? What goes wrong? It would be good to focus your question on that, because now the only thing we can really answer is "Yes, both the presented output and algorithm are correct".

Comment: This is the algo: https://www.cs.rice.edu/~keith/EMBED/dom.pdf; It won't work because the postorder needs 3 before 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the post order traversal of your algorithm is correct. The expected output is indeed as you provided it.

Your confusion may come from the fact that the graph is not a binary tree, and not even a tree. It is a directed graph.

In general postorder means that you first perform a postorder traversal on the node behind the first outgoing edge, then on the node behind its next outgoing edge, ...etc, and only after all outgoing edges have been traversed, the node itself is output.

Since at node 1 you are not at the end yet, and still can go to 2, and from there to 3, you need to follow those edges before outputting anything. And only then backtrack.

For reference, here is your algorithm implemented [in python](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/postorderongraph):

```py
def postorder(root, out_list, children, visited):
    visited[root] = True
    for child in children[root]:
        if not visited[child]:
            postorder(child, out_list, children, visited)
    out_list.append(root)

children = [
    [],      # dummy for node 0
    [2],     # 1
    [1,3],   # 2
    [2],     # 3
    [2,3],   # 4
    [1],     # 5
    [5,4]    # 6 
]

nodes = []
postorder(6, nodes, children, [False] * len(children))

print(nodes) # [3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you got confused with the postorder traversal of binary trees.

Postorder traversal in graph is different.

> **Post Ordering in Graphs** – If we list the vertices in the order in which they are last visited by DFS traversal then the ordering is called PostOrder.

Assuming your root is node is `6`, the order mentioned gives the correct answer.

Checkout the following example on how the post order traversal list is generated:

**Pass 1:**

List:[]

6 -> 5 -> 1 -> 2 -> **3** (Now `Node 3` has no adjacent nodes which are unvisited)

List: [3]

**Pass 2:**

6 -> 5 -> 1 -> 2

`Node 2` has has no adjacent nodes which are unvisited.

List: [3, 2]

**Pass 3:**

6 -> 5 -> 1

`Node 1` has has no adjacent nodes which are unvisited.

List: [3, 2, 1]

**Pass 4:**

6 -> 5

`Node 5` has has no adjacent nodes which are unvisited.

List: [3, 2, 1, 5]

**Pass 5:**

6 -> 4

`Node 4` has has no adjacent nodes which are unvisited.

List: [3, 2, 1, 5, 4]

**Pass 6:**

`Node 6` has has no adjacent nodes which are unvisited.

List: [3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6]

**Important Notes:**

1. As we are using DFS, there can be multiple paths possible depending upon the order of the nodes in the adjacency list.
2. Possible are the correct orders:

   1. [3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6]
   2. [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]
   3. [3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
   4. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]